# $Span(A)\cap Span(B\setminus(A\cap B))=\{\vec 0\}\Longrightarrow Span(A)\cap Span(B)=Span(A\cap B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, span

$A$ and $B$ are two linearly independent sets. $A\cap B = \varnothing$ and $A\nsubseteq B$,$B\nsubseteq A$.

Is the following statement true?:
$$Span(A)\cap Span(B\setminus(A\cap B))=\{\vec 0\}\Longrightarrow Span(A)\cap Span(B)=Span(A\cap B)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer for the original post with $A\cap B=\emptyset$

There is some redundancy.

If $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $B\setminus(A\cap B)=B$, so you are asking whether
$$
\operatorname{Span}(A)\cap\operatorname{Span}(B)=\{0\}
\implies
\operatorname{Span}(A)\cap\operatorname{Span}(B)=\operatorname{Span}(A\cap B)
$$
which is obvious because
$$
\operatorname{Span}(\emptyset)=\{0\}
$$

### Answer for the modified question with $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$

Since the intersection of $\operatorname{Span}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Span}(B\setminus(A\cap B))$ is trivial, we know that
the sum of the two spaces has the same dimension as the sum of the dimensions. Let's call, for simplicity,

- $U=\operatorname{Span}(A)$
- $V=\operatorname{Span}(B)$
- $W=\operatorname{Span}(B\setminus(A\cap B))$

Note that $U+V=U+W$.

Then we know that $\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W$. By Grassmann's formula,
$$
\dim(U+V)=\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\dim(U+V)=\dim U+\dim V-\dim(U\cap V)
$$
so we have
$$
\dim W=\dim V-\dim(U\cap V)
$$
so
$$
\dim(U\cap V)=\dim V-\dim W
$$
Now, $\dim V-\dim W=|A\cap B|$. Since, clearly,
$$
\operatorname{Span}(A\cap B)\subseteq U\cap V,
$$
equality of dimensions make us conclude.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I am sorry there was a typo yesterday. A \cap B should be not empty.

Comment: @user68689 Added answer; however, you shouldn't modify questions if this invalidates already given answers. It's better to ask a new one.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I am new here.